# Solve: $3x≡1 \pmod 7, 4x≡1 \pmod 9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

My attempt:

3x≡1 mod 7 (1)

4x≡1 mod 9 (2)

Multiply (1) by 5

Multiply (2) by 7

x≡5 mod 7

x≡7 mod 9

So x≡9k+7

9k+7=5(mod7)

k=5(mod7)

k=7j+5

x=9(7j+5)+7

=63j+52

x≡52(mod63)

Comment: You change from modulus 7 to 9 midway through the problem. Please proof-read before posting.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I have corrected your title (but don't have the time to correct the formatting in the body of your post). My answer has also pointed out the errors in your working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation (note that $5$ is the multplicative inverse of $3 \pmod 5$),

$3(5)x \equiv 5 \pmod 7 \implies 15x \equiv 5 \pmod 7 \implies x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$. So $x = 7k + 5$

Substitute into the second to give $28k + 20 \equiv 1 \pmod 9 \implies k \equiv -19\pmod 9 \implies k \equiv -1 \pmod 9$. So $k = 9t -1$

So $x = 7(9t-1) + 5 = 63t -2$, giving the solution $x \equiv -2 \equiv 61 \pmod {63}$.

In asker's question, the error is here:

Going from "9k+7=5(mod7)"

to "k=5(mod7)"

is unjustifiable. From the first, we get $9k \equiv -2 \pmod 7$ or $2k \equiv -2 \pmod 7$. That gives $k \equiv -1 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$.

It is also equally unclear how "So x≡9k+7" became "x=9(k)+5" later on. The latter should be $x = 9(k) + 7$.

Correcting for those two errors gives the expected solution (identical to mine).

Comment: How did you get k≡−1≡6(mod7)?

Comment: @P.Graham I divided both sides of $2k \equiv -2 \pmod 7$ by $2$. This is permissible because $(2,7) = 1$ (i.e. $2$ and $7$ are coprime).

Comment: @P.Graham Most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Summing two equations you get $7x=2$, or $0=2$ in mod 7. So no solutions exist.

Comment: I think the problem statement was wrong to begin with (second equation was supposed to be modulo $9$).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that we need $x+2$ divisible by  $7$ and by $9$, hence by LCM$(7,9)$